# Why are my threads not synchronizing?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to get a grasp on synchronizing threads, but I don't understand the problem I'm encountering.

Can someone please help me diagnose this or, even better, explain how I can diagnose this for myself?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class Controller {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int numThreads = 0;
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

    if (args.length > 0) {
        numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("No arguments");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(numThreads);
    int arr[][] = new int[10][10];

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadableClass(barrier, arr));
        threads.add(newThread);
    }

    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.start();
    }
  }
}
```

There is a main method (above) which accepts the number of threads I want as a command line argument. And there is a work-flow (below) which I am aiming to have increment all elements in a 2D array and print the array before the next thread has its chance to do the same:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class ThreadableClass implements Runnable {

private CyclicBarrier barrier;
private int arr[][];

public ThreadableClass(CyclicBarrier barrier, int[][] arr) {
    this.barrier = barrier;
    this.arr = arr;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    System.out.println(threadId + " Starting");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        changeArray();
        try {
            barrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private synchronized void changeArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            arr[i][j]++;
        }
    }
    printArray();
}

private synchronized void printArray() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " is printing: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Imagining the size of the array is 2x2, the expected output would look something like this:

```
1 1
1 1
2 2
2 2
3 3
3 3
4 4
4 4 
...
...
(10 * numThreads)-1 (10 * numThreads)-1
(10 * numThreads)-1 (10 * numThreads)-1
(10 * numThreads) (10 * numThreads)
(10 * numThreads) (10 * numThreads)
```

Instead, all threads increment the array, and begin printing over one another.

Comment: And seriously: this is a great question. You put down all your code, but its not "too much" code; you described the expected and actual output. If now accept in time, you just did a marvelous job ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is **nothing** surprising about the result. You create *n* threads. You tell all threads to start. Each threads run() starts with:

```
long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
System.out.println(threadId + " Starting");
...changeArray();
```

going to change that shared array. **After** writing to the array, you try to sync (on that barrier). Its too late then!

The point is: you have 10 **different** ThreadableClass instances. Each one is operating on its **own**! The `synchronized` key word ... simply doesn't provide any protection here!

Because: synchronized prevents **two** different threads calling the same method on the **same** object. But when you have multiple objects, and your threads are calling that method on those **different** objects, than there is **no** locking! What your code does boils down to:

```
threadA to call changeArray() .. on itself
threadB to call changeArray() .. on itself
threadC to call changeArray() .. on itself
```

...

In other words: you give *n* threads access to that shared array. But then you allow those *n* threads to enter changeArray() at the same time.

One simple fix; change

```
private synchronized void changeArray() {
```

to

```
private void changeArray() {
  synchronized(arr) {
```

In other words: make sure that the n threads have to **lock** on the **same** monitor; in that case the shared array.

Alternatively: instead of making `changeArray()` a method in that ThreadableClass ... create a class

```
ArrayUpdater {
  int arr[] to update

  synchronized changeArray() ...
```

Then create **one** instance of that class; and give that same instance to each of your threads. Now the sync'ed method will prevent multiple threads to enter!

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I see now. Reading through your solution, I decided to create a single instance of ThreadableClass in the Contoller class, then passed each thread that same instance. (Just trying to provide some extra context for the next person to wonder the same thing). Again, thanks GhostCat! You really helped a lot.

Comment: Since you seem to know what you're doing around these parts, are there any stylistic improvements I should make to this? Any customs that I should be following that I'm not? (Happy birthday!!!)

Comment: Just a few; as I should get to bed soon ;-) A) even using a static main; try to do as few things as possible in there. Like: write a method that takes that number "n" and creates a list of threads; and another method that continues to work on them. And you main just reads the number and then calls those methods. B) try to make your fields **final** so the compiler can help you to ensure that they are assigned a value ... exactly one time!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are providing `new` instance for each theard using `new ThreadableClass(barrier, arr)`, basically, **all the theadrs are using different `ThreadableClass` objects**, so your code synchronized methods run parallely, so you need to use a single `ThreadableClass` object as shown below:

```
ThreadableClass threadableClass= new ThreadableClass(barrier, arr);
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
     Thread newThread = new Thread(threadableClass);
     threads.add(newThread);
}
```

The important point is **synchronization is all about providing access (i.e., key) to an object for a single thread at a time**. If you are using a different object for each thread, threads don't wait for the key because each thread has got its own key (like in your example).